# How to make clang search for gcc's headers?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, libc++

I want to replace gcc with clang (3.3) to build my C++11 code, so I should use clang's option `-stdlib=libstdc++` (to make it see STL headers). The option works: clang see headers like `string`, but can't find c++11 headers (`type_traits`) because clang searches in 4.2 directories:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
...
/usr/include/c++/4.2
/usr/include/c++/4.2/backward
/usr/include/clang/3.3
/usr/include
...
```

How to make it look at never versions of GCC's headers?

As far as I understand, only libc++ (not libstdc++) is supported by clang for C++11 so the only way it so install libc++?

Comment: If you want to replace GCC with clang, why do you want to use GCC's standard library implementation? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Can you post the complete output of that command, without the edits?

Comment: How to answer to people with multiple-words-nicknames? :)

Comment: @pavelkolodin You would use `@` followed by the name with all spaces removed.

Answer (score 1):

Either uninstall gcc 4.2 or use the `--gcc-toolchain=<value>` option.

```
--gcc-toolchain=<value> Use the gcc toolchain at the given directory
```

For example: `clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/... -stdlib=libstdc++ ...`

> As far as I understand, only libc++ (not libstdc++) is supported by clang for C++11 so the only way it so install libc++?

Both C++ standard libraries are supported.